# How to parse a Google CSE results located on a site in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, google-custom-search, custom-element

I want to parse a Custom Search Element `JavaScript` function. 
Here's a template of this function https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#overview.

```
<!-- Put the following javascript before the closing  tag. -->
<script>
(function() {
  var cx = '123:456'; // Insert your own Custom Search engine ID here
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want both of the search box and the search results to render -->
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

I want to parse this function from this site http://findmusicbylyrics.com/search.php?cx=partner-pub-1936238606905173%3A1893984547&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=Love&sa=Search+Lyrics which it's `JavaScript` is:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var cx = 'partner-pub-1936238606905173:8242090140';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'http://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Now i have no idea of where to start with it. I've done some `HTML` parsing using java `Jsoup` but this is the first time i bump into  this `CSE` `<script>` tag to parse.
Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517131/best-way-to-parse-google-custom-search-engine-results I saw this SO post but i inderstand nothing from his answer...

Answer (score 1):

> I've done some HTML parsing using java Jsoup but this is the first time i bump into this CSE  tag to parse.

You'll fetch the page and then find the script element. Once done, you'll call the `html()` method on this element.

#### HELPER FUNCTION

```
/**
 * 
 * Extract the Custom Search Element JavaScript of a site.
 * 
 * @param url
 *            The site url
 * @param cssQuery
 *            The query for finding the script element
 * @return the content of the between the tags &lt;script> and &lt;/script>
 * @throws IOException
 *             If the CSE Javscript is not found or an error occured during
 *             {@code url} fetching.
 * 
 */
public static String getCustomSearchElementJavascript(String url, String cssQuery) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Element script = doc.select(cssQuery).first();

    if (script == null) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to find Custom Search Element JavaScript.");
    }

    return script.html();
}
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String url = "http://findmusicbylyrics.com/search.php?cx=partner-pub-1936238606905173%3A1893984547&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=Love&sa=Search+Lyrics+";

System.out.println( getCustomSearchElementJavascript(url, "div#content > script") );
```

#### OUTPUT

```
(function() {
    var cx = 'partner-pub-1936238606905173:8242090140';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'http://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

Comment: I upvoted you but you didn't understood my question. Getting that `JavaScrip` code was not my problem. My problem is what to do with it and how. That `JavaScript` code is off this site http://findmusicbylyrics.com/search.php?cx=partner-pub-1936238606905173%3A1893984547&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=Love&sa=Search. I want to be able to access all those google links. Thank you.

Comment: @God The links are loaded with Javascript. Jsoup won't help here. Use *ui4j* or *Selenium* instead.